# JS Use for loop variable in function definition, without the function changing during iterations

Tags: javascript, for-loop, eval

I am coding a game in which the user must select one of the cards sent from the back-end, but I don't know what cards, or how many, until I recieve them. I must make a button for each, and sent the chosen one to the back end. Since I don't know how many cards there will be, I define each button's action in a for loop.

Since I use the loop variable to acces the numerical code that must be sent to the back-end, after each iteration of the loop the numerical code sent by the function changes.

Here's how I solved the problem:

(cards is an array with the cards, and for any card in it, card['code'] is it's numerical code. The 11 in sendJSON means that the info sent is the chosen card)

```js
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += `<button><img src="Cards/${cards[i]['code'].toString()}.png" width="346" height="529" id="${cards[i]['code'].toString()}"></button>`;

    // Here is the problem:
    eval('document.getElementById(' + cards[i]['code'].toString() + ').onclick = async function f() {await sendJSON(11, ' + cards[i]['code'] + ')}')
}
```

The problem is the eval() since not only it is unsafe, it also has bad performance, so I was wondering...

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`?

Comment: you would be better off using an event delegation

Comment: Just write a function expression! But [close over the right variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're putting the code in the `id` attribute, the event listener can simply use `this.id` to get it, you don't need to copy it into the function.

You also need to use `insertAdjacentHTML()` rather than concatenating to `innerHTML`. When you concatenate, all the HTML in the container is re-parsed, and any event listeners on previous images will be lost. `insertAdjacentHTML()` only parses the new HTML and leaves all the old elements unchanged.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  container.insertAdjecentHTML('beforeend', `<button><img src="Cards/${cards[i]['code']}.png" width="346" height="529" id="${cards[i]['code']}"></button>`);

  document.getElementById(cards[i]['code']).addEventListener("click", async function f() {
    await sendJSON(11, this.id)
  });
}
```

There's also no need for all the `toString()` calls. Substituting into a template literal automatically converts it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the code as a `data-*` property and use the same event handler for every element (or use event delegation as mentioned in the comments). I'd also suggest to not use `innerHTML` for such simple markup, especially not inside a loop (see Barmar's answer for why it won't work anyway):

```
function handler(event) {
  sendJSON(11, event.dataset.code);
}

for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = `Cards/${cards[i]['code']}.png`;
  img.dataset.code = 'code';
  img.width = 346;
  img.height = 529;
  img.onclick = handler;

  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(button);
}
```